# apache not multi process the same php

Tags: php, apache

I create one php to send one file, but before send this file need to check some situations, one situation is a maximum access, can only exist 5 download file per time.

I create php but apache processing one request per time, not all in the same time.

e.g if I make 3 request and put sleep(3) in php file, first request slow 3 seconds, second 6 seconds, and third 9 seconds.

I`m Not understand much about php and apache.
anyone can help me ?

Comment: Are you using sessions in your scripts?

Comment: Some hosts restrict Apache or process totals, but not usually that strictly.

Answer (score 2):

If you use sessions, session is locked per request, so the second, third etc. request must wait until the first finish the process.

If you expect another request while a long process running with the same session you should call

**session_write_close()**
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

explicitly. But only if you don't want to write to the session later in the process.

**Edit:**

If you want to reopen the session later, you can call

**session_start()** http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

(before any output).

Comment: You can always re-open the session with another session_start() if you want. There's no fundamental limit on how many times you can open/close a session within a single script, other than the usual "must be done before any output is sent".